# Wire concrete implementation to interface in blueprint.xml

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel, jax-rs, blueprint-osgi

## Background

Looking to wire a concrete class to a parameter for a REST server's `@POST` method within `blueprint.xml`.

## Problem

Jackson data binding cannot find the concrete implementation for the method's `send` parameter.

## Code

### Java

The REST server has a single `send` method, defined as:

```java
public interface NotificationServer {
    @POST
    Response send(NotificationRequest notificationRequest);
}
```

The `NotificationRequest` is also an interface:

```java
public interface NotificationRequest {
```

A concrete implementation of `NotificationServer`, called `EmailNotificationServerImpl`, implements the interface:

```java
public class EmailNotificationServerImpl implements NotificationServer {
    @Override
    public Response send(final NotificationRequest request) {
```

### Blueprint

The relevant parts of `blueprint.xml` include:

```xml
<bean class="EmailNotificationServerImpl" id="emailNotificationServerImpl">...</bean>
<bean class="NotificationRequestImpl" id="notificationRequestImpl" />
<service interface="NotificationRequest" ref="notificationRequestImpl" />
```

## Exception

The Jackson error message:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of NotificationRequest: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

## Deserialize

It is possible to deserialize the class using:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(as = NotificationRequestImpl.class)
public interface NotificationRequest {
```

While this works, it doesn't fully decouple the implementation from the interface.

## Question

How can the concrete implementation be wired in `blueprint.xml` so that the `@JsonDeseralize` annotation is not necessary?

## Environment

- Java 1.8
- Apache Camel 2.x
- JAX-RS 2.1
- Jackson JAX-RS JSON Provider 2.9.x
- OSGi 1.2.1
- Not using Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom provider that extends [JacksonJsonProvider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/blob/master/json/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.java) in JAX-RS server definition within the `<jaxrs:providers>` tag.

Or use a custom deserializer that extends [StdSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html):

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourDeserializer.java)
```

Or use polymorphism and `@JsonTypeInfo` + `@JsonSubtypes` annotations.